# Performing Math Operations on Pandas [CSV file]: can not merge DataFrame with <class 'list'>

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with LSAT data, which I want to use to extract information from.

**Question: How can I divide two dataframes to get the % of answers correct for each 'Question Type'**

--> For '*Question Type*' in qTypeTotal: divide 'Question Type' *is_correct* True value by '*Question Type*' qTypeTotal value

The following code shows the two pieces of information I need to compare.

*qTypeTotal* returns the each type of question asked, and how many times it was asked.

*correct_answers* returns a DataField with 'Question Type' and whether the answer is correct or not, given as True/False, followed by the number of times True/False

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Kenny/Downloads/logicReasoning.csv')

qTypeTotal = df['Question Type'].value_counts()
print(qTypeTotal)


df['is_correct'] = df['Your Answer'] == df['Correct Answer']
correct_answers = df.groupby(['Question Type', 'is_correct']).size()
print(correct_answers)
```

**Attempt:** DataFrame.merge

```
import pandas as pd

# use dtype to specify data type ex dtype={"name": str, "age": np.int32} 

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Kenny/Downloads/logicReasoning.csv')

qTypeTotal = df['Question Type'].value_counts()
print(qTypeTotal)


df['is_correct'] = df['Your Answer'] == df['Correct Answer']
correct_answers = df.merge(['Question Type', 'is_correct'])
print(correct_answers)
```

**Result:**

File "C:\Users\Kenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 526, in **init**
    'type {right}'.format(right=type(right)))

ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type

**Alternate Attempt:** I've tried to convert a list into a Pandas DateFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Kenny/Downloads/logicReasoning.csv')

qTypeTotal = df['Question Type'].value_counts()
#print(qTypeTotal)

df['is_correct'] = df['Your Answer'] == df['Correct Answer']
correct_answers = df.groupby(['Question Type', 'is_correct']).size()
#print(correct_answers)

dframe = pd.DataFrame(np.array(qTypeTotal.reshape(50,3), columns = list('Question Type')))
print(dframe)
```

**Result:**

File "C:\Users\Kenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4372, in **getattr**
    return object.**getattribute**(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Some sources:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

https://www.ritchieng.com/creating-dataframe-from-objects/

Comment: What about `correct_answers = df.groupby(['Question Type'])['is_correct'].mean()`. This groups by `Question Type`, then for each group, calculates the mean of the `is_correct` column. Since True/False is equivalent to `1`/`0` the mean gives you the percentage correct.

Comment: This is great! I was so focused on having to convert that I completely overlooked this oops.

With that said though, is there a way to convert/merge the question above to that I may perform other operations, perhaps not able to be solved with .mean() or .abc()?

Comment: Looking to merge the QTypeTotal value_counts onto correct_answers